# Getting error "Unwrap could not solve any island(s)" when marking seam and unwrapping?

Tags: uv, vertices

I get the following error when unwrapping after I have selected an edge and marked it as seam:

> Unwrap could not solve any island(s), edge seams may need to be added

Where is the problem?

[image: ?]

Comment: You need to add another seam right across your object at right angles to the one you've marked otherwise the unwrap will fail. Suggest you share your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page to add a link to the file into your question so that we can have a look and advise.

Comment: What do you mean by an "error" - that it is heavily stretched? Imagine how you would flatten this object if it was real - you would need to grab the outer rim with some mechanical arms and pull it in all directions until it's flat (which would work only if it was made from very very stretchy rubber). Otherwise you need to make at least one more cut: https://i.makeagif.com/media/5-15-2017/pVkV0J.gif

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady i think he refers to the warning in the screenshot (at bottom center).